# Google Drive inside TrueCrypt folder

Tags: truecrypt, google-drive

I want my Google Drive files to be locally stored in an encrypted way with TrueCrypt. There are two ways of doing this: put an encrypted folder inside your GDrive-folder, or put your GDrive-folder inside an encrypted folder.

The first option is ok, but this means a lot of upload and download?
The second option is more bandwidth friendly, as only the adjusted files will be up/downloaded. This second option is possible with Dropbox.

However, put the GDrive folder inside an encrypted folder doesn't work for me. Who is able to do this?

Comment: That way round is wrong anyway. I've put my truecrypt containers to the drive folder. Either encrypt it everywhere or save it plaintext.

Comment: Trying to put your GDrive folder onto a truecrypt volume only encrypts your GDrive data ON YOUR MACHINE. If you manage to do that, you'll still have it be only protected by Google's good graces on their servers. The point of putting an encrypted volume on the drive is that YOU are the only one with the decrypted data.

Comment: Please explain in more detail how it doesn't work for you.  Your limited to the way GDrive works, since it will upload the entire file everytime it changes, the first option is the only way you can do this.

Comment: The workaround is not wrong anyway. It is just how I want it to work. I trust Google more with my data than storing the data on my pc. If my PC gets stolen, someone get access to confident data. I have more trust in the securicy of Google :)

Comment: @user13664 - have you considered whole disk encryption? It might actually be easier to use than what you're working toward.

Answer (score 0):

What 'doesn't work'? You've given nothing to go on here, so I'm going to have to guess to try to help you.

Taking the psychic debugging route (warning: prone to just as much error as any other psychic), I'm going to guess that the Google drive app is upset about the fact that the place it's supposed to put it's stuff is missing. IF that's the case, then you'll probably want to disable auto-start on the Google drive app, and start it manually after you've mounted the volume or whatever where you want the drive stuff to land. You could also try just killing the drive app, then mount, then restart the drive app.

Comment: Indeed, Google Drive app is upset about the place where I want him to store the data: the truecrypted drive. The following 'workaround' does **not** work: locate the GDrive on an unencrypted location, sync it all, close GDrive, move the folder to truecrypt folder, open GDrive and locate to the new location. Any help?

Comment: If it's going to work at all, you need to make sure the truecrypt volume is mounted and accessible at all times while google drive is running. So, mount the volume, start google drive, sign in and use advanced setting to put folder on the truecrypt volume. Stop google drive, then unmount truecrypt volume. Only start google drive with the truecrypt volume mounted.

Comment: Maybe use AHK or some other automation utility to incorporate a logic check?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing, for the same reasons.  I share files on Google drive and I don't store anything too secret on there, but if my laptop is stolen, I want the files to be encrypted on the stolen hard drive.

The error I got from Google Drive was "please select a folder on an NTFS drive that is not mounted over a network". I was confused by the network part, but then I realized that the only problem was that TrueCrypt had defaulted to a FAT drive.  I created a new NTFS-formatted container and pointed Google Drive at that and it all works.

Of course Drive complains whenever you start up the computer and the disk is not mounted, but once you get around to mounting it, Drive is happy again.

Answer (score -1):

Google drive should be able to only upload file changes and not the whole file. I use dropbox with an 500mb true crytp container and when i did some testing the file wasnt uploaded in full size when i changed something in the container. There a different methods and file hashes so that the programm hasnt to upload the whole file when you change something.

A file is simply a seqence of zeros and ones and it dosent matter if a file is encrypted or not and when you change a file the file will only change some zeros and ones but not all.

Just test it with a container using a smaller size first.